# Border-radius в ie 6,7

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, чтпбы border-radius заработал в Internet Explorer 6, 7? Есть ли какие-нибудь костыли? PIE.htc пробовал, не помогает, border-radius.htc тоже пробовал, и тоже не помогает.

Comment: PIE работает нормально. Просто указывайте абсолютный путь. Т.е. не от css-файла, а от документа, на котором будет отображение.

----------

P.S. Про осла 6 и 7 порабы уже забыть. На восьмой еще можно ориентироваться, но и то с большим натягом. И только потому, что он по умолчанию ставится с Win7 и не у всех есть возможность его обновить или использовать нормальный браузер (напр., на работе)

Comment: Я то с Вами полностью согласен, и всё понимаю, только понимал бы это заказчик :) А есть ли какие-то другие способы, помимо PIE?

Comment: @baksis2, "помимо PIE" я и не старался что-либо искать, т.к. работает он на 100% и альтернатива просто не нужна. Проверено уже как минимум на семи проектах. Если вы не можете прописать абсолютный путь к файлу (*хотя для меня это останется загадкой года*), то как альтернатива - сделать [подключение с использованием JS][1]

   [1]:http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/

Comment: Решил проблему. pie.htc не работает на вертуалке.